# How to get passed and failed test case count in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to know the total number of failed and passed test cases in my test suite

I know we can fetch total number of testCases by `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseCount()`.

I want to know is there a way so that we can get the required thing from testRunner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SOAPUI documentation [here](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html) you can see the follow script. You can put the code as a `tearDown Script` of your TestSuite using the `tearDown script` tab of your testSuite view:

[image]

```
for ( testCaseResult in runner.results )
{
   testCaseName = testCaseResult.getTestCase().name
   log.info testCaseName
   if ( testCaseResult.getStatus().toString() == 'FAILED' )
   {
      log.info "$testCaseName has failed"
      for ( testStepResult in testCaseResult.getResults() )
      {
         testStepResult.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg }
      }
   }
}
```

This script logs the name of each testCase, and in case that the testCase fail show the assertion failed messages.

A more groovier script to do exactly the same and also counts the total number of testCase failed could be:

```
def failedTestCases = 0

runner.results.each { testCaseResult ->
    def name = testCaseResult.testCase.name
    if(testCaseResult.status.toString() == 'FAILED'){
        failedTestCases ++
        log.info "$name has failed"
        testCaseResult.results.each{ testStepResults ->
            testStepResults.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg } 
        }
    }else{
        log.info "$name works correctly"
    }
}

log.info "total failed: $failedTestCases"
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i wanted a solution without any teardown script. I did a little workaround by playing with suite parameter. Since, this answer is working perfectly, marking it as correct

Comment: @UdayNaik can you please post or explain more  what you have tried with suite parameter.