# Loop through all test cases and test steps in SOAP UI using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

As part of the Test Suite teardown process, I want to loop through all the Test Cases and Test Steps that were run previously and capture the results and the assertions.  I'm not very good at groovy script, this seems like it would be straight forward to do, but so far it hasn't gone well.  This mainly because I am not familiar with the object model and there is no "intellisense" to guide me.  I just need a shell to start out with.

Also, I have a loop that executes the same test step multiple times feeding in a different set of data.  I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Here's my shell:

```
def testCases = context.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList()
testCases.each
{
    log.info "~~~Test Case:" + it.name
    for(testSteps in it.testStepList)
    {
        log.info "~~~Test Step:" + testSteps.name
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error...
`Wed Nov 04 15:53:44 EST 2015:ERROR:An error occurred [Cannot get property 'testSuite' on null object], see error log for details`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233938/how-to-get-passed-and-failed-test-case-count-in-soapui/33234534#33234534) what you are trying to achieve getting all the results for runned testSuite.

About your error:

`Wed Nov 04 15:53:44 EST 2015:ERROR:An error occurred [Cannot get property 'testSuite' on null object], see error log for details`

The problem is that if you're testing your `tearDown script` executing alone (out of testSuite) directly using the play button in `tearDown script` there are some missing variables, in this case context.testCase which is null this is why you get this error message. This variables are only available if you execute the whole testSuite.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it in the *TearDown Script* of the test suite, then below snippet can help you

```
testSuite.testCaseList.each {
   log.info "Test Case : ${it.name}"
   it.testStepList.each {
      log.info "Test Step : ${it.name}"
   }
}
```

Note that, teardown script of a testsuite can use below variables which can also notice in soapUI as well

```
log, context, runner, testSuite
```

Comment: This answer is useful as well.Although I don't completely understand the "it" syntax.

Comment: Let me give a brief what it does. A test suite contains list of test cases. Then taking each of it (test case) then logging the name of it as an  example, of course, we add business logic if needed here. Again each test case contains list of test steps, and looping thru each of it. Hope it is better now.